# Cannot stop PE orgs seeing tabs

Tags: managed-package, permissions, professional-edition

Please note that question refers specifically to PE orgs and not those with profile settings (DE/UE/EE etc..). I have been testing with managed beta packages.

I have an app defined that has a set of VF tabs that act as admin pages and standard object tabs. What I want to do is hide these admin tabs and allow an admin user to specify who can have access.

I have created the tabs as hidden and a permission set (tabAdmin) to show them. (This works fine in DE btw.) Upon installing the package in PE tabs are always visible even for users without the permissions sets assigned.

Ultimate goal is to have tabs that can be switched on/off dependent on settings provided by an admin user. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What I'm going to do, as this doesn't seem possible, is create an admin screen and use permission sets to show/hide links to the pages behind the existing tabs. I'll also check permission set assignment on each page to stop 'hacking' attempts. Current tabs will be removed as redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This was done intentionally. This requires customizable profiles which is an add-on in professional edition or requires an upgrade. Please reach out to your sales rep to discuss your options. Please add your voice and vote to this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpxBAAS

Comment: There is a solution using permission sets to turn the tabs on/off. These can be assigned in PE orgs to achieve functionality required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a JavaScript sidebar component to hide certain tabs?  Professional Edition is very limited.  See below.

Knowledge Article Number: 102445

Description
Can I turn certain tabs on or off for users in my company?

Resolution
Salesforce.com allows each user to customize his or her display, including control of which tabs are turned on and which related lists are displayed on each detail page.

For Professional Edition, display customization is a user-specific setting. There is no way for an administrator to turn tabs on or off for all users at once.

If you are a System Administrator, you can forward these instructions to your users to have them turn Tabs on or off:

```
           1. Log into Salesforce.

           2. Click on:

            Setup | Personal Setup | My Personal Information | Change My

            Display |Customize My Tabs.

           3. Select the desired tab from the selected tabs or available tabs list.

           4. Click remove or add to move the tab to the available tabs list or

            selected tabs  list.

           5. Click "Save".
```